# Ember passing an action closure through an outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building a simple Ember app, but I have run into difficulty passing an action closure to a child component when that component is rendered in the `{{outlet}}` of a navigable container.

For context, here is a quick look at the aesthetically-astonishing app I have been building:

[image]
I have a `roles/role` path that displays a component (the yellow section above) with the following markup. Note that the model for this component is an instance of a Role:

```
// file: app/components/role.hbs

<p>{{@role.name}}</p>

<div>
  {{sel-nav-tabs items=this.tabConfig}}
  <div class='route-content'>{{outlet}}</div>
</div>
```

(Where "sel" stands for "someone else's library".)

this.tabConfig is defines in the corresponding class:

```
// file: app/components.role.js

import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class RoleComponent extends Component {

  get tabConfig() {

    return [
      { label: 'Users', route: 'roles.role.users' },
      { label: 'Privileges', route: 'roles.role.privileges' },
    ];

  }

}
```

Into the outlet in role.hbs will be rendered the appropriate list component, either `users` or `privileges`.

The users list is rendered by the following component. Note that the model is the list of User instances associated with the Role from its parent:

```
// file: app/components/role/user-list.hbs

<ul>
  {{#each @users as |user|}}
    <li>
      {{user.name}}
      {{#sel-button type="toolbar" onActivate=this.removeUser}}
        {{sel-icon/remove-circle}}
      {{/sel-button}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and when the button is clicked it calls an action defined in the RoleUserListComponent class:

```
// file: app/components/role/user-list.js

import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class RoleUserListComponent extends Component {

  @action removeUser(user) {
     // remove the user model from the role... but which role?
  }
}
```

The catch is that the relationship between users and roles is many-to-many, so I can't simply unset the user's owner and let Ember Data take care of things. The obvious answer seemed like passing an action closure from the role component to its child user-list component.

Except, there seems to be no way to pass the action closure through the `{{outlet}}`. What I was hoping for was something like:

```
{{outlet onActivate=(action removeUser @role)}}
```

which would pass the closure to any component that was rendered there. I tried instead to use `{{yield user}}` in the child to let the parent render the delete button and give it the appropriate action, but that also hit the outlet wall.

I also tried to use controllers, which aren't documented that well, probably since their role seems to have been evolving dramatically over Ember's maturation. But while [this brief explanation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/controllers/) does mention passing down actions, it doesn't go into details, and the few up-to-date examples I found all seem to break when an outlet joins the party.

I'm suspecting that `{{outlet}}` just plain isn't closure-friendly.

While defining a service would probably work, that doesn't seem to be what services are intended for, and I'd be cluttering up my global space to solve a local problem.

What is the best practice (or, really, any practice) for dealing with getting messages through outlets? I looked for ways to query the earlier parts of the path, but I didn't find any that were defined in the relevant classes.

EDIT to add more detail:

The route template for `/roles/role` is simply:

```
// file app/templates/roles/role

{{role role=@model}}
```

Where the Role component is in the first listing above. (I also added the role.js file contents above.) My reasoning for doing that was that by making a component I created a logical place to put the config (rather than inline helper functions) and it just gave me a sense of tidiness to have all ui elements be in components.

If a refactor can be the anchor to a good solution (essentially copying the entire Role component into the route template), however, I'll happily do it.

Comment: Hi, I am surprised that you are using `outlet`s in components, they are usually only used in route templates. Can you say a bit more about that so I can fill out my answer?

Comment: Interesting. I'll add more detail to the above. Refactoring is a possibility if moving the `{{outlet}}` to the route template gives me new options.

Answer (score 1):

[`{{outlet}}`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/outlet?anchor=outlet) only supports one optional string argument for a named outlet and nothing else, so you won't be able to achieve this through the use of `{{outlet}}`!

Comment: Yeah, that was part of my 'things I tried that didn't work' list above. I subsequently found the part of the docs that spelled that out. It would be cool if that did work, however...